# Sweet.js - Can macros be used in more than one file?

Tags: javascript, macros, sweet.js

I've got macros defined in file 'A'. I'd like to use the macros in other files, e.g. file `B`.

Is this possible? I know of course that I could use the compiled results of the macro in file `B`, but I'd like to use the macro there too.

**A**

```
macro test {
 ...
}

test 1
test 2
```

**B**

```
test 3
test 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `--module` flag and `export` your macro in file A. It's documented [here](http://sweetjs.org/doc/main/sweet.html#modules).

Comment: Does this also work for `syntaxes` and `operators` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can surely do it!

You'll need to export the macro and pass the file name as a parameter when compiling.

Look this:

**set.sjs**

```
macro set {
    rule { $i:ident = $value:lit } => {
        var $i = $value;
    }
}
export set;
```

**id.sjs**

```
macro id {
    rule { $i:ident } => 
    {
        $i;
    }
}
export id;
```

And while compiling:

```
 => # sjs --module ./set.sjs ./id.sjs
```

Comment: Does this also work for `syntaxes` and `operators` ?